# How can I open a modal component programmatically?

Tags: angular, ng2-bootstrap

I'd like to open a modal programmatically like a modal service. This is how I did it in angular 1 :

`uibModal.open({template:'url.html', controller: MyController})` that way I wouldn't need to add modal HTML code to my parent screen.

Let's say I have this folder structure:

```
components
-- screen1
---- parent.component.ts
-- modal1
---- modal1.component.ts
---- modal1.template.html
-- modal2
---- modal2.component.ts
---- modal2.template.html
```

then on `parent.component.ts` I'd like to open `modal1`

But since the modal I'm opening is dynamic I'd like it to open like a service (or anything similar). So I'm passing the information to my `parent.component` of which modal it should open, and then using a modal service (like in angular1) it opens the modal.

How can I approach this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `angular-ui/bootstrap` port to Angular 2 which has a service equivalent to `uibModal`: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal

Its usage is equivalent to the Angular 1.x version - you just call the `open()` method on a service! Here is an example:

```
export class NgbdModalComponent {
  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) {}

  open() {
    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(NgbdModalContent);
  }
}
```

Here is a live example: http://plnkr.co/edit/4pgz0My5Mnt4VoAkIsPa?p=preview

Comment: Hey man, I was checking your lib before posting here (since it's the same one I use for angularjs, but it's still in alpha right? Would you recommend I use it anyway? Thanks :)

Comment: It is _very_ stable and we are _super_ close to going into Beta / RC cycle (a matter of 2 weeks or so). So yes, I would say it is stable and tested so in practice probably more stable than some of the 1.x libs out there :-)

Comment: Ok :) Going for it then :)  Thanks!

Comment: Oh, one more question... you are using BS4 which is currently also in alpha. I'm using BS3.3.7. Would it work with BS3 or only BS4? Thank you

Comment: never mind, I just tested, it is working with BS3. Thanks.

Comment: Oh man. I've been looking everywhere for how to close the modal from child and It's just `ActiveModal.close()`